# Google Extension chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener Loop Trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web

I am working on basic chrome extension,this extension have one mission that mission is when user going a youtube page takes page url and add a GET parameter end of the url im using google extension api and tabs.onUpdated.addlistener for watch user browser actions but when user going a video page tabs.onUpdated.addlistener cause loop therefore browser refresh every time.

My codes in this link https://codeshare.io/2KPvqP

```
**manifest.json**

{
  "name": "Old Youtube",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup" : "view.html"
  },
  "icons" : {
    "16"  : "icon-16.png",
    "48"  : "icon-48.png",
    "128" : "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
 "tabs"
  ],
    "background":{
    "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
  }
}

**background.js**

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        var url=tab.url;
        var search = url.indexOf("www.youtube.com");
        var variable = url.indexOf("GETPARAMETER");
        var get = url.indexOf("?");

        if (search>0) 
        {
            if (variable<0) 
            {
                if (get>0)
                {
                    chrome.tabs.update({url: tab.url+"&GETPARAMETER"});

                } 
                else{
                    chrome.tabs.update({url: tab.url+"?GETPARAMETER"});

                }
            }
            else 
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: put your code in code sample format

Comment: When I entered this post, I tried to add the code in the sample format, but it failed every time